# how to handle general protection fault in linux kernel

Tags: kernel, general-protection-fault

I have a piece of kernel module as the following, which tries to read msr register, no doubt it would crash as the msr 0x2 is not exist, a geneal protection fault will happens.
My question is how could I bypass this fault, like define my GP handler? if I cannot read a msr, just let it go...

The following is my module code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

#define LBR 0x2 

static unsigned long long x86_get_msr(int msr)
{
    unsigned long msrl = -1, msrh = -1;

    /* NOTE: rdmsr is always return EDX:EAX pair value */
    asm volatile (
                   "rdmsr;"
                   : "=a"(msrl), "=d"(msrh)
                   : "c"(msr));

    return ((unsigned long long)msrh << 32) | msrl;
}

static int helloworld_init(void) {
    unsigned long long ullRet = -1;

    ullRet = x86_get_msr(LBR);
    printk(KERN_INFO "msr: 0x%08x, ret: 0x%016llx", LBR, ullRet);
    printk(KERN_INFO "hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}


static void helloworld_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "see you.\n");

    return;
}

module_init(helloworld_init);
module_exit(helloworld_exit);
```

The following is the message:

```
[19353.498488] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[19353.498491] Modules linked in: helloworld(POE+) nls_utf8 isofs xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs overlay crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd input_leds snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec serio_raw ac97_bus joydev snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer vboxguest(OE) snd soundcore mac_hid binfmt_misc sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev sunrpc lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid hid vboxvideo(OE)
[19353.498548]  ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm psmouse pata_acpi pcnet32 mii i2c_piix4 ahci libahci video
[19353.498555] CPU: 1 PID: 7379 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-91-generic #92-Ubuntu
[19353.498556] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[19353.498560] RIP: 0010:x86_get_msr+0x25/0x3d [helloworld]
[19353.498561] RSP: 0018:ffffb92e46477c40 EFLAGS: 00010282
[19353.498563] RAX: 0000000000000002 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000002
[19353.498564] RDX: 000000000003f8e0 RSI: ffff9e3d4fdba500 RDI: 0000000000000002
[19353.498565] RBP: ffffb92e46477c58 R08: ffff9e3d5fd26080 R09: ffffffff8302c54e
[19353.498566] R10: ffffe11380ccfa40 R11: ffff9e3d5ffd1000 R12: ffffffffc092e03d
[19353.498567] R13: ffff9e3d4fdbaf80 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff9e3ce8adede0
[19353.498569] FS:  00007f6e90008540(0000) GS:ffff9e3d5fd00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[19353.498571] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[19353.498582] CR2: 000055aabbc97e88 CR3: 00000000b1924006 CR4: 00000000000606e0
[19353.498599] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[19353.498600] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[19353.498601] Call Trace:
[19353.498605]  helloworld_init+0x1f/0x4e [helloworld]
[19353.498609]  do_one_initcall+0x52/0x19f
[19353.498612]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x40
[19353.498614]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x14e/0x1b0
[19353.498617]  ? do_init_module+0x27/0x213
[19353.498619]  do_init_module+0x5f/0x213
[19353.498621]  load_module+0x16bc/0x1f10
[19353.498624]  ? ima_post_read_file+0x96/0xa0
[19353.498627]  SYSC_finit_module+0xfc/0x120
[19353.498629]  ? SYSC_finit_module+0xfc/0x120
[19353.498632]  SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
[19353.498634]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[19353.498636]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[19353.498638] RIP: 0033:0x7f6e8fb2f839
[19353.498639] RSP: 002b:00007ffd5b22f348 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[19353.498640] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055aabbc957a0 RCX: 00007f6e8fb2f839
[19353.498641] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055aababe6d2e RDI: 0000000000000003
[19353.498642] RBP: 000055aababe6d2e R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f6e8fe02000
[19353.498643] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[19353.498644] R13: 000055aabbc95760 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[19353.498646] Code: <0f> 32 48 89 45 f0 48 89 55 f8 48 8b 45 f8 48 c1 e0 20 48 0b 45 f0 
[19353.498655] RIP: x86_get_msr+0x25/0x3d [helloworld] RSP: ffffb92e46477c40
```

Comment: AFAIK there are special functions to handle msr read/write, checkout: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/lib/msr-smp.c#L169